# will setting pthread_canelState to PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE queue up the cancellation requests?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am trying to understand Posix threads. In the man page of pthread_cancel(), it is mentioned that "thread’s cancelability state, determined by pthread_setcancelstate(), can be enabled or disabled. If a thread has disabled cancellation, then a cancellation request remains queued until the thread enables cancellation.

But when I was reading about thread cancellation points on http://www.makelinux.net/alp/029, it is mentioned that if we set the cancel type as disabled (uncancellable), the cancellation requests are quietly ignored.

Can any one please let me know whether cancellation requests are getting queued or ignored if we set the cancellation type as DISABLED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX threads controls thread cancellation by a combination of **two** binaries variables:
cancellation **STATE** and cancellation **TYPE**. The associated functions are **pthread_setcancelstate()** and **pthread_setcanceltype()** accordingly. 
When the **STATE** is set to disabled, the cancellation request is ignored.
It is not thrown out, it is suspended (or as you correctly wrote - "queued"), until the **STATE** is set back to enabled. Since the state is enabled, the OS starts the cancellation process according to the cancellation type. If you have a code that must be executed before a thread is cancelled (e.g. memory de-allocation etc.), you may set the thread cancellation state to disabled, before entering the code, and enable the cancellation exiting the code. The second question is how and when the thread is really stopped (cancelled). The the cancellation **type** answers this question. If the type is set to (not recommended) **asynchronous**, the cancellation may occur at the nearest instruction. If the type is set to the default **deferred** cancellation, the cancellation will occur at the next "cancellation point", a POSIX function that checks thread cancellation status and terminates the thread.